# Add custom argument to WP_Query and modify SQL where clause

Tags: wp-query, sql

I'd like to be able to hook into WP_Query in such a way that I can add a custom argument to my WP_Query like:

```
$q = new WP_Query([
  'my_cool_arg' => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
]);
```

and then access this and modify the where part of the generated SQL query. I am aware of the **posts_where** filter, but I don't know how to access the arguments from that filter.

Comment: What exactly should this custom argument do

Comment: I'm interested in a general solution to the problem. But as an example let's say I want to append an EXISTS statement to the WHERE clause that queries a custom table in the database using an IN generated from the array I provided. Generating the SQL isn't a problem for me, I just need to find a way to access the argument while modifying the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The filter **posts_where** takes the query object as a second parameter.